# Incorrect Syntax near '-' .(Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, syntax-error

While doing SSIS job I got an error in my create table query

> Incorrect Syntax near '-' .(Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0)

SQL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Staging_ACD_Precision_Queue 
(
    PrecisionQueueID int,
    BucketIntervalID int,
    EnterpriseName varchar(32),
    AgentOrdering int,
    CallOrdering int,
    Description varchar(255),
    ServiceLevelThreshold int,
    ServiceLevelType smallint,
    ForceExpandingQueue varchar(1),
    Deleted varchar(1),
    ChangeStamp int,
    Partner varchar(4),
    Center varchar(4),
    Partner-Center varchar(9),
    LOB varchar(4),
    Circle varchar(4),
    TypeOfBusiness varchar(4)
)
```

I tried the above query. I guess from the error message that, the issue is in `Partner-Center varchar(9)` but I failed to fix this error. Since I'm new to SSIS and SQL queries I don't know to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: you need to use square brackets: `[Partner-Center]`

Comment: AFIK In SSIS we can't use square brackets, that's the main problem. I tried with square brackets also.

Comment: Why not follow the naming convention for the rest of the fields and call it PartnerCenter?

Comment: Where did you read that SSIS doesn't allows them?, that's just wrong

Comment: If with brackets failed in SSIS, it would have failed with a different error message I'm guessing. Is that right?

Comment: @Lamak You are right. Now I correctly used with square brackets and the error has been fixed. :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Honestly, I'd work hard to not use the hyphen character at all -- especially since you're creating the table right here and can probably do whatever you want.  Just go with PartnerCenter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put square brackets around `Partner-Center`, e.g. `[Partner-Center]`. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed in field names, but you can escape them by putting the field name within square brackets.

```
CREATE TABLE Staging_ACD_Precision_Queue (
    PrecisionQueueID int,
    BucketIntervalID int,
    EnterpriseName varchar(32),
    AgentOrdering int,
    CallOrdering int,
    Description varchar(255),
    ServiceLevelThreshold int,
    ServiceLevelType smallint,
    ForceExpandingQueue varchar(1),
    Deleted varchar(1),
    ChangeStamp int,
    Partner varchar(4),
    Center varchar(4),
    [Partner-Center] varchar(9),
    LOB varchar(4),
    Circle varchar(4),
    TypeOfBusiness varchar(4)
)
```

As others have stated here, I too would like to recommend you avoid using a hyphen in the field name and go with either `Partner_Center` or `PartnerCenter` as the field name instead of `Partner-Center`.

Comment: +1, correct, you need square braces `[Partner-Center] varchar(9)`, but I'd recommend that you avoid names with any special characters in them. Our naming standard prevents any special characters.  Also, this column looks strangely like the previous two columns (`Partner varchar(4), Center varchar(4)`), is it possible this is redundant combined data? doesn't pass my smell test.

Comment: @KM I hope not, because it is one character less than then combined length of Partner and Center.

Comment: @Donal Probably because there's a `-` between them ;-)

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not allow `-` in bare field names. However, you can "escape" it by surrounding the field name with square brackets (`[]`):

```
CREATE TABLE Staging_ACD_Precision_Queue (
    PrecisionQueueID int,
    BucketIntervalID int,
    EnterpriseName varchar(32),
    AgentOrdering int,
    CallOrdering int,
    Description varchar(255),
    ServiceLevelThreshold int,
    ServiceLevelType smallint,
    ForceExpandingQueue varchar(1),
    Deleted varchar(1),
    ChangeStamp int,
    Partner varchar(4),
    Center varchar(4),
    [Partner-Center] varchar(9),
    LOB varchar(4),
    Circle varchar(4),
    TypeOfBusiness varchar(4)
)
```

Comment: Can you cite this information for SQL Server 2008 (since the OP referred to SNC 10.0? I have only been able to find this for SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have "-" in column names.  you can do underscores. but not minus signs.

Actually you can however you have to [ ] around column name to create with a dash and everytime you want to access you have to [var]

Change

```
Partner-Center varchar(9),
```

to be

```
Partner_Center varchar(9),
```

or

```
[Partner-Center] varchar(9)
```